# Passing variable from loop to main function

Tags: c++

I'm taking an intro c++ class and I have a question that resulted from a homework assignment. The assignment asked for two variables (ints) to be validated using a function. The assignment was to reject an invalid variable, which would end the program. I am trying to set up a loop that will ask for and validate new inputs from the user if the first inputs are invalid. I feel like this makes more sense, as the user wouldn't have to close and open the program again.

Here is where I hit a snag: I'm using a loop to get and validate the variables so if the first variables are invalid I can prompt for and validate new inputs but they will be local to the loop. How can I pass validated inputs from the loop back to the main function? My variables ("yr1" and "yr2" are defined globally, which I thought would solve my problem). I thought the answer would be a return statement, but I can't get that to work either.
Lastly, since I am new to this I expect that my code isn't laid out that well. If you have any suggestions as to how to make my code more readable, I am happy to listen. Thank you for for time.

Here's the code:

```
    void getDate ()
    {
        // Get the starting year
        cout << "Please enter the starting year" << endl;
        cin >> yr1;
        rangeCheck (yr1);


        // Get the ending year
        cout << "Please enter the ending year" << endl;
        cin >> yr2;
        rangeCheck (yr2);

        if (yr1 > yr2)
            {
                cout << yr1 << "-" << yr2 << " Invalid range error. Please try again." << endl;
                getDate();
            }

        else if (yr1 == yr2)
            {
                cout << yr1 << "-" << yr2 << " These years match. Please try again." << endl;
                getDate();
            }
    }
```

P.S. rangeCheck() is a function that validates the validates the variable. makes sure that the numbers are between 1900 and 2099, that yr2 > yr1, and that they are not the same. The rest of the program runs a leap year calculation to determine how many leap years fall withing the range of the inputs.

I'm sorry for the length of the post.

EDIT: Here are the main

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    //Function declarations
    void rangeCheck ();
    void getDate();
    void leapCalc(int);

    //Variable declarations
    int yr1;
    int yr2;
    int years = 0;
    int leap;
    //int leap; //<< " " << leap

    //Main
    int main()
    {
        cout << "Please enter any two (2) years between 1900" << endl;
        cout << "and 2099 and this program will determine" << endl;
        cout << "how many leap years fall between them." << endl;
        cout << endl;

        getDate();

        for (int leap = yr1 ; leap < yr2; )
            {
            leapCalc(leap);
            leap++;
            }

        cout << yr1 << " " << yr2 << " " << years << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the rangeCheck function

```
    void rangeCheck (int day)
    {
        for ( ;day ;)
        {

            if (day < 1900 || day >2099)
            {
                cout << day << " is an invalid entry. Please try again." << endl;
                getDate();
            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `rangeCheck()` return a value you need to test or does it throw an exception if that check fails?

Comment: If you're going to return more than one value you may need to use a container like [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or make this function take `(int& yr1, int& yr2)` as arguments that are mutable.

Comment: please add your `main()` or whatever function is calling `getDate()`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Having a lengthy post is in its own way a good thing. The better you explain your problem and recreate it in your question, the easier it is for the community to answer it for you.

Comment: It sounds like you're overthinking this assignment; command line applications typically exit as soon as something unexpected happens. No need to make this more complicated than needed. Just print an error message and quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I assume your loop is outside the function? 
I further assume that rangeCheck is setting one global, like `isValid`.

So if your first number is invalid, then the global will be false, but then the second is valid, then that will set `isValid` to true, so even though the input was invalid, it will not be noted.  You should probably have `rangeCheck` return true or false if it is valid or not valid.

You also need getDate to return a boolean, so that you will know if the individual responses were valid.